# jQuery "Circle Shape" Animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, geometry

http://www.beautifulexplorer.com/main.html?skip=1

When you first open this website there is pie-chart that is center-wipe-animated or sth like that. 
I looked up the code and it seems like its jQuery but I just wanted to know if there is a more isolated example of this type of mask(?) animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That particular example is done via the `<canvas>` tag of [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element).

Here's some [examples of animations and effects](http://blarnee.com/wp/12-new-examples-of-advanced-animation-with-jquery/comment-page-1/).

If have more questions, comment and I'll try and help.