# Animated Circular bar on hover

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, geometry

I'm building a portfolio website and want to implement a skill set page which feature an animated circular bar which represent each of my skills. There will be 6 buttons around the circle which when the user hovers over, and when one is hovered I want a circular bar to animate anti-clockwise.

I've made a quick .gif in photoshop to demonstrate But I can't find any tutorial to help.

I found this website which features a similar concept on the left hand side at the top, an animated pie chart - [Website Example](http://www.beautifulexplorer.com/main.html?skip=1)

And this is a quick .gif Mockup I did in photoshop of what I am trying to achieve - [Animated Circular Bar Animation](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/33996415.gif/)

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606024/jquery-circle-shape-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Website you linked to did its animation with a HTML5 `canvas` element, which has a good [support in modern Browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/canvas#Browser_compatibility).

You can find good [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Canvas) with a nice [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial).

Another alternative might be [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) which has support even for older Browsers and it might be simpler to use. Check out [this example](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html).

Comment: I've not come across Raphaël, looks like this may be the ticket! thank you for your help and fast response!